# Неправильное поведение svg. Баг?

Tags: css3, svg, css-animation

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xahon/pqptk7to/)
`SVG` сделан в иллюстраторе. Ожидается то, что каждый `polygon` будет вращаться относительно своего центра, кажется так и есть, но вращается еще и `g`, почему?

Answer (score 2):

Ты так хотел?
http://codepen.io/geek_of_cola/pen/jrxJLN
если так то просто добавь css3 animation:

```js
var b = "rot 4s ease-in-out";

$('polygon').css({
  animation: b
});
```

```css
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

g {
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}

.st0 {
 opacity: 0.93;
 fill: url(#SVGID_1_);
}

.st1 {
 fill: url(#SVGID_2_);
}

.st2 {
 fill: url(#SVGID_3_);
}

.st3 {
 fill: url(#SVGID_4_);
}

.st4 {
 opacity: 0.92;
 fill: url(#SVGID_5_);
}

.st5 {
 opacity: 0.85;
 fill: url(#SVGID_6_);
}

.st6 {
 fill: url(#SVGID_7_);
}

.st7 {
 fill: url(#SVGID_8_);
}

.st8 {
 fill: url(#SVGID_9_);
}

.st9 {
 opacity: 0.93;
 fill: url(#SVGID_10_);
}

.st10 {
 opacity: 0.68;
 fill: url(#SVGID_11_);
}

.st11 {
 opacity: 0.84;
 fill: url(#SVGID_12_);
}

.st12 {
 opacity: 0.84;
 fill: url(#SVGID_13_);
}

.st13 {
 opacity: 0.44;
 fill: url(#SVGID_14_);
}

.st14 {
 opacity: 0.47;
 fill: url(#SVGID_15_);
}

.st15 {
 opacity: 0.72;
 fill: url(#SVGID_16_);
}

.st16 {
 opacity: 0.6;
 fill: url(#SVGID_17_);
}

.st17 {
 opacity: 0.54;
 fill: url(#SVGID_18_);
}

.st18 {
 opacity: 0.5;
 fill: url(#SVGID_19_);
}

.st19 {
 opacity: 0.74;
 fill: url(#SVGID_20_);
}

.st20 {
 opacity: 0.83;
 fill: url(#SVGID_21_);
}

.st21 {
 fill: url(#SVGID_22_);
}

.st22 {
 opacity: 0.31;
 fill: url(#SVGID_23_);
}

.st23 {
 opacity: 0.46;
 fill: url(#SVGID_24_);
}

.st24 {
 opacity: 0.59;
 fill: url(#SVGID_25_);
}

.st25 {
 opacity: 0.59;
 fill: url(#SVGID_26_);
}

.st26 {
 opacity: 0.3;
 fill: url(#SVGID_27_);
}

.st27 {
 opacity: 0.13;
 fill: url(#SVGID_28_);
}

.st28 {
 opacity: 0.59;
 fill: url(#SVGID_29_);
}

.st29 {
 opacity: 0.48;
 fill: url(#SVGID_30_);
}

.st30 {
 opacity: 0.51;
 fill: url(#SVGID_31_);
}

.st31 {
 opacity: 0.44;
 fill: url(#SVGID_32_);
}

.st32 {
 opacity: 0.44;
 fill: url(#SVGID_33_);
}

.st33 {
 opacity: 0.56;
 fill: url(#SVGID_34_);
}

.st34 {
 opacity: 0.58;
 fill: url(#SVGID_35_);
}



@keyframes rot {
 0% {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="50px" y="50px"
  viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">  
   
<g>
 <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="2.6042" y1="19.5833" x2="33.6458" y2="19.5833">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st0" points="33.6,10.6 2.6,8.9 15.6,30.3  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="4.8147" y1="13.2871" x2="35.401" y2="-4.3719">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#301083"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5B097F"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st1" points="40,3.6 33.6,10.6 2.6,8.9 0,4.9 0,2.1 4.3,0 34.9,0  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="34.8958" y1="1.7969" x2="62.6042" y2="1.7969">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st2" points="62.6,0 40,3.6 34.9,0  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="67.8125" y1="15.4948" x2="40" y2="15.4948">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#361E8A"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st3" points="56.3,31 40,3.6 62.6,0 67.8,20.4  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="15.625" y1="21.6667" x2="47.7083" y2="21.6667">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#751888"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st4" points="47.7,39.7 47.1,15.5 40,3.6 15.6,30.3  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="47.0837" y1="27.6172" x2="56.2745" y2="27.6172">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5B0174"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st5" points="56.3,31 47.7,39.7 47.1,15.5  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_7_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="62.6042" y1="4.4531" x2="88.75" y2="4.4531">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#630B80"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st6" points="88.8,8.9 64.7,8.3 62.6,0 83.6,0  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_8_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="100" y1="4.4531" x2="83.6458" y2="4.4531">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#6D268F"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#0B0247"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st7" points="100,3.6 88.8,8.9 83.6,0 100,0  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_9_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="64.7328" y1="9.5443" x2="99.951" y2="9.5443">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#2E2A8F"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#881284"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st8" points="90.7,15.5 64.7,8.3 88.8,8.9 100,3.6 100,7  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_10_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="64.7328" y1="21.7917" x2="90.7292" y2="21.7917">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#6D1F8B"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st9" points="71.6,35.3 67.8,20.4 64.7,8.3 90.7,15.5 87.3,20.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_11_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="72.9326" y1="23.3207" x2="59.517" y2="46.5573">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0C155E"/>
   <stop  offset="0.9847" style="stop-color:#7D0171"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st10" points="74.7,47.6 71.6,35.3 67.8,20.4 56.3,31 47.7,39.7  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_12_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="71.5625" y1="37.6562" x2="95.5208" y2="37.6562">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st11" points="95.5,37.4 87.3,20.2 71.6,35.3 74.5,46.9 76.8,55.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_13_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="87.2917" y1="22.2396" x2="99.951" y2="22.2396">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5B0174"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st12" points="100,32.8 95.5,37.4 87.3,20.2 90.7,15.5 100,7  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_14_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="75.6771" y1="44.5052" x2="100" y2="44.5052">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#7D0171"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st13" points="75.7,56.2 76.8,55.2 95.5,37.4 100,32.8 100,56.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_15_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="34.8958" y1="46.102" x2="76.7708" y2="46.102">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="0.9694" style="stop-color:#5E1486"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st14" points="53.9,56.2 34.9,36 47.7,39.7 74.7,47.6 76.8,55.2 75.7,56.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_16_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="30.625" y1="46.102" x2="64.7328" y2="46.102">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#723797"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st15" points="30.6,56.2 31.3,53.2 34.9,36 64.7,52.6  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_17_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="15.625" y1="41.7209" x2="34.8958" y2="41.7209">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="0.5102" style="stop-color:#881284"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#681D8A"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st16" points="15.6,30.3 34.9,36 31.3,53.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_18_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="15.9006" y1="58.0881" x2="28.2414" y2="45.7474">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0B0049"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#701788"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st17" points="14.1,56.2 21.8,39.3 31.3,53.2 30.6,56.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_19_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1.982698e-010" y1="45.5469" x2="30.625" y2="45.5469">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#78258E"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st18" points="0,34.8 21.8,39.3 30.6,56.2 5.6,56.2 0,52  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_20_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1.982698e-010" y1="29.1919" x2="21.7982" y2="29.1919">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#630051"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st19" points="8.8,19.1 0,23.2 0,35.3 21.8,39.3 15.6,30.3  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_21_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1.982698e-010" y1="13.8151" x2="8.8074" y2="13.8151">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#100126"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st20" points="0,4.5 0,23.2 8.8,19.1  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_22_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1.982698e-010" y1="1.0677" x2="4.2708" y2="1.0677">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#080335"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st21" points="4.3,0 0,2.1 0,0  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_23_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-1.982698e-010" y1="54.1406" x2="5.625" y2="54.1406">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st22" points="0,56.2 0,52 5.6,56.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_24_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="2.6042" y1="75.8333" x2="33.6458" y2="75.8333">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st23" points="33.6,66.8 2.6,65.2 15.6,86.5  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_25_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="31.0134" y1="56.2925" x2="64.3253" y2="56.2925">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st24" points="64.3,52.6 40.1,60 31,56.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_26_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="67.8125" y1="69.906" x2="40" y2="69.906">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#361E8A"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B95AAA"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st25" points="56.3,87.2 40,59.8 64.7,52.6 67.8,76.6  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_27_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="15.625" y1="77.9167" x2="47.7083" y2="77.9167">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#751888"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st26" points="47.7,96 47.1,71.7 40,59.8 15.6,86.5  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_28_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="47.0837" y1="83.8672" x2="56.2745" y2="83.8672">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5B0174"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st27" points="56.3,87.2 47.7,96 47.1,71.7  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_29_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="64.7328" y1="58.8644" x2="88.75" y2="58.8644">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#630B80"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st28" points="88.8,65.2 64.7,64.6 64.7,52.6 83.6,56.2  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_30_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="100" y1="57.2629" x2="83.6458" y2="57.2629">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#6D268F"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#0B0247"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st29" points="100,59.8 88.8,65.2 83.6,56.2 100,49.4  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_31_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="64.7328" y1="65.7943" x2="99.951" y2="65.7943">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#2E2A8F"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#881284"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st30" points="90.7,71.7 64.7,64.6 88.8,65.2 100,59.8 100,63.3  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_32_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="64.7328" y1="78.0417" x2="90.7292" y2="78.0417">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#6D1F8B"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st31" points="71.6,91.5 67.8,76.6 64.7,64.6 90.7,71.7 87.3,76.4  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_33_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="87.2917" y1="78.4896" x2="99.951" y2="78.4896">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5B0174"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st32" points="100,89 95.5,93.7 87.3,76.4 90.7,71.7 100,63.3  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_34_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-2.601155e-010" y1="70.0651" x2="8.8074" y2="70.0651">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0A0744"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#100126"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st33" points="0,60.7 0,79.4 8.8,75.3  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_35_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.9289" y1="68.0029" x2="34.5153" y2="50.3439">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#301083"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5B097F"/>
  </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st34" points="40,59.8 33.6,66.8 2.6,65.2 0,61.2 0,58.4 0.3,54.1 31,56.2  "/>
  <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                    attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="0 50 50"
                    to="360 50 50"
                    dur="0s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</g>

</svg>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Да, так хотел. Но нужно без `animation`, потому что угол поворота у каждого будет рандомный

Comment: так дулируешь с keyframes те параметры, тобиш `transform: rotateZ(свои парамерты)` && `transform-origin:50% 50%` и пулишь рандом

Comment: Как я через javascript изменю параметры `keyframes`? Или можно как-то так передать `animation: {transform: scale(2);} 2s ease;`?

Comment: вот такая функция есть http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: `.animate({"transform" : "rotate(20deg)"}, 1000);` не работает

Comment: если все равно будешь писать на `js` для разных классов, проще тебе создать это все `keyframes` выделить для каждого эффекта класс и приписывать его `polygon` и удобно и красиво и без js нагрузок

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46681/discussion-between-lieutenant-jim-dangle-and-herrgott).